# Parse REST API: Proper way to query class object with ACL (python)

Tags: android, python, objective-c, rest, parse-platform

There are three classes in my Parse database. For some reason, fetching data from the second class ContactsData always returns an empty result. Would be great if anyone could provide insights into the problem!

**1. The default "Users" class**

No problems getting data from this class following examples at https://parse.com/docs/rest#users

ACL column is empty

**2. A custom "ContactsData" class. A user is allowed to add name and phone of contacts  through our iOS app**

Custom columns: name (string), phone (number)

ACL is write: true and read: true.

What I want to do: Fetch all contacts of a given user using python REST API.

**METHOD 1:**

```
import json,httplib
import apikeys
import dataset

MY_CLASS = '/1/classes/ContactsData'
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
connection.connect()
connection.request('GET', MY_CLASS, '', {
       "X-Parse-Application-Id": apikeys.PARSE_APP_ID,
       "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": apikeys.PARSE_REST_API_KEY,})

parseData = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
print parseData
```

Output:

```
{'results':[]}
```

Keep getting this even when there are objects in this class

**METHOD 2**

Also tried MY_CLASS = '/1/classes/ContactsData/ABCDEFG' where ABCDEFG is the objectId of a particular object.

Output:

```
{'code': 101, 'error': 'requested resource was not found'}
```

**3. A custom "Testing" class**

Exactly the same as MY_CLASS. Just that I did not use ACL, and created the object directly from the Parse dashboard. This time, I was able to get the data using 
MY_CLASS = '/1/classes/Testing'

Answer (score 2):

You're use REST calls without any logged in user/session-token, so you'll be using default permissions. Unless you've set the class to allow anonymous reads and the row ACL also doesn't restrict it, you wont get any data.

If you want to do the requests as a User that does have read rights to the row you'll need to login and then use the session-token in the headers.

More information can be found here:

https://parse.com/docs/rest#users